# find a number that is repeated between 2 columns, n consecutive times

Tags: python, file, time-series, multiple-columns, repeat

I want to find the number of line where is repeated between two columns from text file during n times, for example 500 times.

My text file is like this (have a lot of lines):

```
0.85    0.00    1
0.85    0.45    2
0.97    0.14    3
0.91    0.05    4
0.97    0.97    5
0.0     0.1     6
0.45    0.0     7
0.0     0.0     8
0.0     0.0     9
0.0     0.0     10
```

and my script attempt is :

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    c = 0
    for i in f:
         for w in i:
            if w[0] == w[1]:
               c+=1
            if c == 500:
                print(i-498)
                break
            else:
                c=0
                print(i)
```

I want to have the number of line (column 3) where for example the number 0 is repeated at leat 500 consecutive times in the column 1 and 2. The output would be like this (supposing from line number 8 the 0 is repeated 500 times between column 1 and 2)

```
0.0     0.0     8
0.0     0.0     9
0.0     0.0     10
```

can you help me to fix it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split each line before comparing and convert the values to floats.

Try this code. For testing, it searches for 2 consecutive lines. Change it to 500 for your run.

```
ss = '''
0.85    0.00    1
0.85    0.45    2
0.97    0.14    3
0.91    0.05    4
0.97    0.97    5
0.0     0.1     6
0.45    0.0     7
0.0     0.0     8
0.0     0.0     9
0.0     0.0     10
'''.strip()

with open ('list.txt','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file
   
#############################

rep = 2   # change to 500
with open('list.txt') as f:
    c = 0
    for i in f:
        w = [float(n) for n in i.strip().split()]
        if w[0] == w[1]:
           c+=1
           if c == rep:
              print('>>> line', int(w[2]))
              break
        else:
            c=0
            print(i.strip())
```

Output

```
0.85    0.00    1
0.85    0.45    2
0.97    0.14    3
0.91    0.05    4
0.0     0.1     6
0.45    0.0     7
>>> line 9
```